# Use the Mean Value Theorem on the interval $[2, 2.1]$ to show that $\frac{1}{15} \leq f(2.1)−f(2) \leq \frac{1}{5}.$

Tags: calculus

Let $y=f(x)$ be a function, defined implicitly by $2(x−y)=3+\cos y$ that is continuous on the closed interval $[2, 2.1]$ and differentiable on the open interval $(2, 2.1).$ Use the Mean Value Theorem on the interval $[2, 2.1]$ to show that $\frac{1}{15} \leq f(2.1)−f(2) \leq \frac{1}{5}.$

This is all I have so far:

$$f '(x) = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$

$$f '(x) = \frac{f(2.1)-f(2)}{2.1-2} = \frac{f(2.1)-f(2)}{0.1}$$

I am stuck on what to do next.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Shamim Well at this point I have tried everything, I've done a ton of research and watched a ton of videos. This is the closest I got to answering the question. I just added my work.

Comment: Nice, remember to always add whatever you have tried, however small be the attempt.

Comment: @Shamim Thanks for helping, I appreciate it, this is my first time here.

Comment: where is it given that $2<f'(x)<2.1$?

Comment: In the problem itself it describes the function of f and describes it as differentiable on the open interval (2, 2.1), so I applied it to the derivative of the function f(x), which is f '(x)

Comment: I believe that means that the function $f(x)$ is differentiable for $2 < x < 2.1$ which does not imply that $2 < f'(x) < 2.1$

Comment: @WestonMiller Okay, thanks for the clarification!! This gets me one step closer, but to be honest I am still confused on how to apply that information to answer the question

Comment: I seem to remember a very similar question from when I was in calculus that was part of a multi-part problem. The solution required information from a previous part (I believe it gave the range of $f'(x)$). Is there any additional information given? The only other way I can think of to procede is to determine the range of $f'(x)$ from the given equation.

Comment: @WestonMiller Yes in fact this is part of a multi-part question, but the previous parts do not provide useful information because they are asking to find concavity, differentiate implicity and find tangent line slopes. I could add in that information, but I don't think it will be useful to solving this part of the question.

Answer (score 3):

carrying on from where you left, see that 
$f(2.1)-f(2)=(0.1)f'(x) $ for some $x\epsilon(2,2.1)$ according to the mean value theorem.

Now, if you differentiate your given implicit equation , you get
$f'(x)=\frac{2}{2-\sin(y)}$ ,  whatever be the value of y, $  -1\le\sin(y)\le1\;\; \Rightarrow 
\ 1\le(2-\sin(y))\le3
$  so $ \frac{2}{3}\le f'(x)\le 2$ and $  \frac{1}{15}\le(0.1)f'(x)\le\frac{1}{5}$

Comment: Thank you so much!!!